# Jquery exclude element that not have <a href="#"> inside

Tags: jquery

how can I exclude from this selection element that not have a href="#" inside of it?
I want my stuff is executed only for .leading that have a href="#"...
thank you

```
//js
$(".leading").hover(function(){
// do stuff
}

//DOM
<div class=".leading"><div ><a href="#"> <img src="img1.jpg" /> jquery affected </a></div></div>
<div class=".leading"><div ><img src="img2.jpg" /> jquery not affected </div></div>
```

Comment: sorry... <!--<div class=".leading"><div ><a href="#"> <img src="img1.jpg" /> jquery affected </a></div></div>
<div class=".leading"><div ><img src="img2.jpg" /> jquery not affected </div></div>-->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this I believe:

```
$('.leading:has(a[href=#])');
```

Note, your classes should not have a dot `.` prefix in the HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

`$("div.leading div a[href='#']")`

... will select only those anchor tags with a `href` attribute set to the value `#`.

You can then use `.parent().parent()` to walk up to the `div.leading` element.

Also in your example HTML you are using `.leading` as a class name which is invalid, it should be `leading`.

Comment: Thank you, i think i'm near succed... I don't have #, but different links inside my link, i want only exlude div that have link inside. thank you again

Comment: You can also use "div.leading div not(a[href='#'])" to only select those links that don't have a href="#" attribute setting.

Comment: I would like to completely delate href from unusefull item, to avoid hand cursor problems (etc), i'm trying to exclude div thath not have href inside...